# Copy HTML to clipboard while keeping some of the formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a way to copy HTML content to the clipboard, and then paste it using some sort of formatting for specific situations.

For now, I just do a .text() in jQuery so I get the content in plain text in my clipboard. The idea is to copy the content of an article in a wiki-type application, and then paste it in a helpdesk software (like BMC Remedy).

What I would like to do is to retain formatting for element like bullets lists and ordered lists by forcing a new line.

Example: 
HTML is

```
<ul>
<li>bullet #1</li>
<li>bullet #2</li>
<li>bullet #3</li>
</ul>
```

Pasted content would be:
bullet #1
bullet #2
bullet #3

Any idea?

Thank you very much for help

Comment: You can't natively copy to the clipboard, you'll have to use a Flash-based solution.  Luckily there's an [easy(ish) plugin](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard) you can use that will take care of your heavy lifting of getting text into the clipboard.

Comment: You'll have to handle formatting the text yourself though.

Comment: I use the following JS command and it works for copying to the clipboard: if (window.clipboardData) window.clipboardData.setData("Text", myText);

Comment: I am developing for Intranet projects so maybe this is allowed by a policy.

Answer (score 0):

Copying `html elements` rather than just `text` will preserve your formatting. but pasting field should be rich textbox

Comment: Copying the HTML elements will preserve the formatting of the *markup*, but not necessarily the actual text. Plus, you'll also be getting the HTML and not the text, which is what OP seems to require.

Comment: All I need is to retain some of the formatting so it is readable. Otherwise, all words are getting placed one after the other so you loose the text structure (paragraphs, bullets lists, etc.)

Comment: if you paste html formatted code (like <ul>
<li>bullet #1</li>
<li>bullet #2</li>
<li>bullet #3</li>
</ul>) in your BMC Remedy, what is the result it is showing? does it retain formatting?

Comment: @wakqasahmed Well, the HTML code and the is getting copied, as Remedy's worklog is a free text field.